# How long should I wait an answer of the Google android - add-ons review team?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have requested review for my app more than one month ago. It is add-on for Google Sheets. Without that review i can't use app normally, so, google, how long I should wait?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [We're not \[customer-support\] for Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1595451). Maybe on [Developing add-ons for G Suite](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494) you could get some orientation.

Comment: I do not know why these questions are being voted to close. This is the forum as per the docs to ask these questions. There are many people having issues with getting approval, do not close we need a response!